# Working too hard

Tags: calisthenics

I have worked with calisthenics for over a month now, and now I want to work harder for my goal. I am 15 years old and my parents say that I work out way too hard. I exercise 6 times a week. My exercise form Monday, Wednesday, and Friday are doing pull ups, dips, push ups, and squats. I do 12 reps and 8 sets of these exercises. On Tuesday, Thursday, and Saturday, I am doing cardio like burpees, mountain climbers, high knees, and jumping squats trying to burn fat. I really don't feel any soreness the day after. Am I over training?

Comment: Just to note, not to contradict what I stated earlier; if you are able to complete nearly 100 pull ups every other day, not to mention 12 reps a set, you already should be pretty fit and muscular, anyway.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is be fit and happy about my body. I'm not worried about getting buff right now. I know calisthenics won't get me super buff, but I know it will get me in shape. I also will like to do tricks and moves shown in youtube videos. I will also like a six pack like everybody else.

Answer (score 2):

For natural training, it's usual to make 3 to 5 anaerobic sessions per week, but it's hard to know if someone is overtraining just by knowing it's training schedule, basically because everybody is different. I would say as long as your cardio is not very intense, keep training sessions under 1h and eat properly in order to recover, you are ok.
A first check to know if you are overtraining is when you feel a little bit tired all day long.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are working way too hard. I have injured myself before doing a similar routine(believe me, it takes a while to heal). My body did not give me any hints at first when I hurt myself doing this, so watch out. Anyway, you should get a real routine together. I would suggest going to your school's fitness center, and doing a routine such as chest, shoulders, and legs for an hour on Monday and Thursday and doing back and biceps on Tuesday and Friday; that would give you plenty time to recover and it probably would be more effective for muscle gains than your current workout, anyway. Overtraining is not something you want to get involved with, change your routine before you get hurt.

Comment: I am with you when you say a complete routine will be better, but when you say he is overtraining it might not be certainly true. Note he is doing a lot of pullups. That might be because he doesn't weights very much. And being new in body training, his muscles are not that big so they don't need so much recovery time. Also note he is doing 8 setsofeach exercise and doesn't repeat muscle groups, so it is ok to work them more than once a week. I am not saying he is not overtraining, just that it is not that clear, so we should give him tools to know if he is or not.

Comment: @Krotanix The fact here is that he is a beginner, so he probably is not familiar with most warning signs yet anyway, but even so it is possible that one day he will wake up with a problem that will take a while to go away. I kept doing endless push ups, and there was no warning signs for a significant amount of time. I just woke up and had an injury.

Comment: @Krotanix It is just better to do a few sets with 8-12 reps; those reps tidbits exercises that put lots of strain on your body is not good for you; basically calisthenics is okay but doing unlimited numbers of sets and reps is just asking for shit, and calisthenics isn't highly effective for muscle gain, it is more of a fat burner. The OP should begin weight training, in my opinion.

Comment: I apologize for my error, the site won't let me edit it for some reason, tidbits is supposed to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Really appreciate it. I will start a new complete routine for myself.

Comment: Well yes, I admit he could do things better, and that he might be doing too many sets of too few exercises. Doing more and more sets may lead to an injury, but doing 8 sets of calisthenics with a good warmup shouldn't lead to an injury. But again, this is not the way to go and adding more sets would change things. A complete routine with more variety would put him in the good direction to learn basics about bodybuilding.